# Interleaving array in C

Tags: c, arrays, interleave

I posted earlier, but I did not properly format or add my code. Say I have an int array x = [1,2,3]. Given a value i, I want to create an array x^i, such that, if i = 3, array x^i = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]. If i = 5, array x^i = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5]. I am dynamically allocating memory for this.

However, my code for i = 3 is creating an array = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]. I've tried many different things, and I got something like [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] or [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3] but never the correct answer.

Here is my code:

```
void binary_search(int size_a, int * A, int size_x, int *X, int max_i, int min_i){

    int i, j, k, count = 0, max_repeat = 0;

    while(min_i <= max_i){

    int repeats = (max_i + min_i)/2;

    int * temp = realloc(X, size_x * sizeof(int) * repeats);
    X = temp;


    for(k = 0; k < size_x; ++k){
    int idx = size_x - k -1;
    temp = &X[idx];
        for(j = 0; j < repeats; ++j){
            X[idx * repeats + j] = *temp;
        }
    }

    printf("New X: ");
        for(i = 0; i < size_x * repeats; i++){
            printf("%d ", X[i]);
        }

    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size_x * repeats; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < size_a; j++){
            if(A[j] == X[i]){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count == size_x * repeats){
        printf("Low: %d Mid %d High % d Passes\n", min_i, repeats, max_i);
        min_i = repeats + 1;
    }
    else
        printf("Low: %d Mid %d High % d Fails\n", min_i, repeats, max_i);
        max_i = repeats - 1;
    }

}
```

the variable repeats represents the value i in x^i.

The output is this:

```
Old X: 1 2 3 

New X: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 Low: 0 Mid 3 High  6 Fails

New X: 1 1 1 Low: 0 Mid 1 High  2 Fails

New X: Low: 0 Mid 0 High  0 Fails
```

The first iteration is correct, however, the second iteration should not be [1,1,1], it should be [1,2,3].

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why the `max_i` and `min_i` params. Just pass `max = max_i - min_i` and pass `X` using `&X[min_i]`.

Comment: That's for a binary search that I have to compare X with another array A.  I will worry about fixing that when I can figure out how to properly populate X.

Comment: Just create it from the back. Start with the last digit, not from the first. At first copy the `3` three times.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
int misleading_function_names_is_bad_practice(size_t xsize, int x[xsize], size_t i)
{
    void * const tmp = realloc(x, xsize * sizeof(*x) * i);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
       return -__LINE__;
    }
     x = tmp;

     for (size_t k = 0; k < xsize; ++k) {
         // index of the last original digit counting down
         const size_t idx = xsize - k - 1;
         const int tmp = x[idx];
         for (size_t l = 0; l < i; ++l) {
              // fill from the back
              x[idx * i + l] = tmp;
         }
      }

      return 0;
}
```

Live example available at [onlinegdb](https://onlinegdb.com/Sye-l9r5m).

Comment: That kinda worked. It worked for the first iteration of my binary search, but not the second. I am editing my post to show you what changes I made.

Comment: Edited original post. Could you take a look?

Comment: This is only valid for upsizing the array. For downsizing you should process the array from front. I leave that to you as a training exercise. Also you posted some data, some x values, as expected output, but without input values, so i can only deduce them. I don't know, you meant to run in the third line for `i = -3`? `size_t` is unsigned, so you need to use another datatype. If I could give you an advice, take a step back, get yourself a paper and pen and rethink your design.